# How to separate paracetamol and caffeine?

Tags: melting-point, mixtures

How do you separate paracetamol and caffeine using high-school laboratory equipment?

I was thinking about using the fact that paracetamol has a lower melting point (169 °C) compared to caffeine (around 235 °C): I would heat them up till paracetamol melts while caffeine is still solid. What I can't figure out is how you filter the caffeine from the liquid paracetamol (filter paper would burn at such a high temperature).

I would like to know how you do the filtration at high temperature; or, if you have a better method, please let me know!

Comment: Caffeine is basic, paracetamol acidic. Any clues?

Comment: @Waylander Would you like to elaborate on your idea as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that my teachers had in mind was column chromatography. Essentially we use the van der Waals force of silicon gel to do an elution of the caffeine / paracetamol solution dissolved in water.

More details can be found here:
http://www.chemguide.co.uk/analysis/chromatography/column.html

Comment: I will mark this as accepted since there are no other answers.